# Flask-SocketIO refuses connection when deployed

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am currently working on a social network webapp that includes chat functionality, the chat works fine when I'm on localhost.
The problem I have is, that I get an error from SocketIO when I try to connect the client to the (hosted) server.

The error looks like this: GET http://127.0.0.1/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N1Kh0TS net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Now, I've tried troubleshooting this with random solutions on the web for a long time, but I can't quite wrap my head around this.

the run.py:

```
from random import app, socketio

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

in my routes.py my connect-event looks like this:

```
@socketio.on('user_con')
def receive_connection(data):
    # join the desired channel
    join_room(data['channel'])
    print('User ' + str(data['user']) + ' successfully joined channel : ' + str(data['channel']))
```

the client side connects like this:

```
//Connect the socket to our server
   var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');
        socket.on('connect', function() {
          var connection_data = {
            user : '{{ current_user.id }}',
            channel : '{{ channel.name }}'
          }
          //send the connection data
          socket.emit('user_con', connection_data);
        });
```

Please note that the code works really well on the local machine, but not deployed. Everything is hosted on a linux server.

I would really appreciate your help. **Thanks.**

EDIT2: This is our nginx file

```
server {
    server_name #censored#;

    location /static {
        alias /home/admin/Prototyp_1/#censored#/static;
    }

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/#censored#/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/#censored#/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}

server {
    if ($host = #censored#) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = #censored#) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name #censored#;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

edit3: we added the following to our code

```
    location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io;
    }
```

interestingly, when we change the port in the html to 5000, the error is 'conection refused', when it's 8000 the error is 'origin not allowed'

Comment: generaly the common port is usd 8080 0r 80 what is the logic to use 8000

Comment: i guess i meant not flask runs on 8000 but gunicorn, since that is the default port for gunicorn?

Comment: Have you seen the Flask-SocketIO documentation regarding how to configure nginx? https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-nginx-as-a-websocket-reverse-proxy.

Comment: in nginx default is 80 port where location server_name _ is the variable that should define above for your url and location /socket.io  here also should provide the currect path